# Best way to implement "history of edits" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, diff, edit

I want users to be able to see what was added / changed in a blog post. I'm using [Vestal Versions](http://www.railslodge.com/plugins/1549-vestal-versions) (great gem) to keep track of changes, but I don't know how to show this to users so they can see what has changed.

My first impulse is to find a diffing library for ruby and just show the diff between version N and version N-1. What's a good library for this? Is there a more abstract way to do this?

Also, does anyone have any opinion on whether Vestal Versions is better than [`acts_as_audited`](http://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited/tree/master)?

Answer (score 1):

As for the first question, you should check out [HTMLDiff](http://github.com/myobie/htmldiff/tree/master), which gaves you a diff method that compares changes and shows them with proper HTML tags (ins, del) which you can then style with CSS.

I've not used acts_as_audited, but from looking through it's Github page, seems similar. Maybe someone with more experience in both could bring some light to it :)